# Open side menu with modal

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, side-menu, ion-menu

I’ve just worked with Ionic for few days and stuck with this. Every time I open a modal I couldn’t swipe the sidemenu and any pages that I push or setroot in that modal are not able to open sidemenu too.

I have a page. - PedidoCadastroPage.

And Call this method:

```
  public abrirListagemProdutos() {

if (this.abaEscolhida == "PRODUTOS")
  if (!this.formPedido.get('fk_id_cliente').value) {
    this.exibirToastSelecionarCliente();
  } else {
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create("ProdutoListagemPage", {
      pedido: this.formPedido.value,
      mapPedidoProduto: this.gerarMapPedidoProduto()
    });

    modal.onDidDismiss(pedidoProdutos => {
      this.formPedido.get('pedidoProdutos').setValue(pedidoProdutos);
      this.atualizarSomaTotalEQuantidadeDeItens();
    });

    modal.present();
  }
}
```

And try to open the side menu, but nothing happen.

When I close the modal the side menu is open in PedidoCadastroPage

Comment: *and any pages that I push or setroot in that modal are not able to open sidemenu too*: Could you please include the code where you push a new page from the modal?

Comment: Sorry man, in my modal i didn't do thar, i dont set root ou push any page on modal, my only problem is the side menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

Changed the modal to PAGE and put: persistent="true" on the

Like this:

```
<ion-menu persistent="true" [content]="menuFiltro" side="right" id="cliente" (ionClose)="filtroClienteClose()">
```